# cannot use alias in npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack

im trying to create a npm package that i can use in my other app. in my development i defined path in tsconfig for importing different modules instead of relative path. however, when i download my package in to test app. it cannot resolve module path.

i think if i change to using relative path then it would work.

in my tsconfig, i defined a path like this

```
"moduleOne": ["./moduleOne/src/index.ts"]
```

in my ts file where i need to import moduleOne
i do

```
import {helper} from "moduleOne"
```

when i download the package in my other app i get Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moduleOne'

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
import { helper } from "moduleOne"
```

Comment: sry, i do have quotes around moduleOne. the problem is in the compiled js file it is still require("moduleOne"), i thought ts compiler should use the path alias.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the string quotations around moduleOne on the import.

Comment: sry, i do have quotes around moduleOne. the problem is in the compiled js file it is still require("moduleOne"), i thought ts compiler should use the path alias.

Comment: Ah, I see. You shouldn't specify the specific path file. So instead of this:

    "moduleOne": ["./moduleOne/src/index.ts"]
Try this:

    "moduleOne": ["./moduleOne/src/*"]